# Parse microdata using apache tika plugin on apache nutch

Tags: solr, hbase, nutch, microdata, apache-tika

my objective is to 
- crawl on urls and 
- extract micro data and 
- save to solr

I used this [guide](https://github.com/renepickhardt/metalcon/wiki/simpleNutchSolrSetup) to setup nutch, hbase, and solr

Im using [nutch](http://nutch.apache.org) to crawl on urls and [hbase](http://hbase.apache.org), im using tika pluggin for nutch to parse pages, but it only gets meta data.

Did I miss something to config? please guide me or suggest alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your own [ParseFilter](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/2.x/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/ParseFilter.java) and implement the extraction logic there. You will get a DocumentFragment generated by the Tika parser and could use e.g. XPath to get the micro data.

Note that the DOM generated by Tika are heavily normalised / modified so your Xpath expressions could possibly not match. Maybe better to rely on the old HTML parser instead.

One generic way of doing would be to use [Apache Any23](https://any23.apache.org/) as done for instance in [this storm-crawler module](https://github.com/PopSugar/storm-crawler-extensions/tree/master/microdata-parser).

BTW There is an [open JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-980) for a MicroDataHandler in Tika which hasn't been committed yet.

HTH

Comment: using MicroDataHandler,  how can I implement it using Tika plugin in Nutch